# How to call traits method from the class method that uses that trait if both methods name are same?

Tags: php, traits

```
trait World {

    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "World!";
    }
}

abstract class AbstractHello{}

class Hello extends AbstractHello {
    use World;

    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "Hello";
        $this->sayHello(); // calling its not working
    }
}

class Hello2 extends AbstractHello {
    use World;
}
```

Now if I call as follows, it should show "HelloWorld!"

```
$h = new Hello();
$h->sayHello();
```

And If call as follows, it should show "World!"

```
$h = new Hello2();
$h->sayHello();
```

I do not want to change the traits method name using as operator because sayHello() method has been called from other places for child class like Hello2.

Above code is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

In your `Hello` class you have to create alias for `sayHello()` method of trait.

```
class Hello extends AbstractHello {
    use World
    {
        sayHello as sayHelloWorld;
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo "Hello";
        $this->sayHelloWorld(); // calling it's working now
    }
}
```